# CSS Div overlay in responsive design

Tags: html, css

I need to have 4 over layering divs on a div that needs to be centered. The 4 divs should each be at the corners.

I was able to get this to work but unfortunately, when I resize my screen, it goes haywire.

Can someone please help me correct this code to make it look like the following image?

[image: image of what I am trying to achieve]

My Code is

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 14px/24px "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
}
.box-set,
.box {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.box-set {
  background: #eaeaed;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.box {
  background: #2db34a;
  border: 2px solid #ff7b29;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}
.box-1 {
  left: -5%;
  top: -15%;
}
.box-2 {
  bottom: -15%;
  left: -5%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.box-3 {
  left: 88%;
  top: -15%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box-4 {
  bottom: -15%;
  left: 88%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box-set">Year sales
    <figure class="box box-1">Jan 1100</figure>
    <figure class="box box-2">Feb 2200</figure>
    <figure class="box box-3">March 3300</figure>
    <figure class="box box-4">April 4400</figure>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code. I removed the margins on the figure tags. Is this what you want.See below.

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 14px/24px "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
}
.box-set,
.box {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.box-set {
  background: #eaeaed;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
top:200px;
width:50%;
display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;
}
.box {
  background: #2db34a;
  border: 2px solid #ff7b29;
  height: 80px;
 line-height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 0;/**Added this**/
}
.box-1 {
  left: -5%;
  top: -15%;
}
.box-2 {
  bottom: -15%;
  left: -5%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.box-3 {
  right: -5%;/**Added this**/
  top: -15%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box-4 {
  bottom: -15%;/**Added this**/
  right: -5%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box-set">Year sales
  <figure class="box box-1">Jan 1100</figure>
  <figure class="box box-2">Feb 2200</figure>
  <figure class="box box-3">March 3300</figure>
  <figure class="box box-4">April 4400</figure>
</div></body>
```